# How can I check via software if my iPhone is unlocked?

Tags: iphone, unlock

I have a carrier-unlockable iPhone. That means **they sell it locked but will unlocked upon request**.

As is generally the case with carriers, mine is a sack of incompetence. I requested the unlock and got many different responses and directionless guidance in the process. I have reason to believe it may be the case that *they did attempt to unlock it at some point*.

**I'd like to know how I can check wether my device is still carrier-locked or not.**

I'm on a Mac, and I'm enrolled in the iPhone developer program. It would be of more general use to have an answer that doesn't depend on the latter, tho.

While "just pop in a SIM card from another carrier" is a technically feasible answer, I'd rather have one that doesn't involve my getting off my chair.

Comment: Great question; I'd also like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 4):

So in the end I had to do the SIM card dance.

In fact, it seems what the carrier does is mark your phone as allowed for unlock.

Then, the first time you put a SIM card from another carrier, you must connect to iTunes, which will then perform a series of annoyances and alerts and whatnot, and only then your device will be truly unlocked. You need an internet connection for this process.

I know this is a terrible answer to my own question.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell there's only two was to do this:

1. Put a SIM card in from another network.
2. Call your operator and trust their answer.

The Google doesn't offer much more help than this either.

Comment: I'm afraid it's even worse, you have to put the SIM from another carrier, AND plug into iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

How many Apple devices do you have? If you have 100+ iOS devices or 50+ Macs you can apple for an [Apple Direct Service](http://www.apple.com/support/programs/ssa/) account which would give you access to GSX (Apple's service platform for 3rd parties) to check the activation profile (and whether it's locked or not) of iOS devices. It even comes with an API.

Apart from that, no. There isn't a way to determine in with software only.

Answer (score -1):

Now there are online portals which tell you if your iPhone is locked or unlocked that too for free. All you need is to put your IMEI number and check for details. One such place to find the status is http://iosbasics.com/iphone-operator-check

Comment: Which now says "However, simlock check and carrier check will not be available through this tool."

Comment: You didn't try it before adding your comment here. Did you?? Yes, it doesn't give carrier info now. But it does tells if your iPhone is locked to unlocked.

Answer (score -4):

Check (1P) Part No. on the box

**Locked**

*Germany - T-Mobile*

MC603DN/A – 16GB Black

MC605DN/A – 32GB Black

*Japan - Softbank*

MC603J/A - 16GB Black

MC605J/A - 32GB Black

*Spain - Movistar, Orange, Vodafone*

MC603Y/A – 16GB Black

MC605Y/A – 32GB Black

*United States - AT&T*

MC608LL/A - 16GB Black

MC610LL/A - 32GB Black

*Apple*

MC318LL/A - 16GB Black

MC319LL/A - 32GB Black

**Unlocked**

*Australia*

MC603X/A - 16GB Black

MC605X/A - 32GB Black

*Canada*

MC603C/A - 16GB Black

MC605C/A - 32GB Black

*France*

MC603FB/A - 16GB Black

MC605FB/A - 32GB Black

*Hong Kong*

MC605ZP/A - 32GB Black

MC603ZP/A - 16GB Black

*Italy*

MC603IP/A - 16GB Black

MC605IP/A - 32GB Black

*New Zealand*

MC603X/A - 16GB Black

MC605X/A - 32GB Black

*Singapore*

MC603ZA/A - 16GB Black

MC605ZA/A - 32GB Black

*Sweden*

MC603KS/A – 16GB Black

MC605KS/A – 32GB Black

*United Kingdom*

MC603B/A - 16GB Black

MC605B/A - 32GB Black

Comment: It does not ship unlocked. I have to request the unlock to the carrier. I want to confirm that they succeeded at it.

Comment: When I purchased my unlocked iPhone from the Apple Store, I had to ensure that my SALES RECEIPT indicated no contract, which would prevent the phone from being locked once a SIM was inserted.  Further reading here: http://www.howardforums.com/showthread.php/1664561-Unlocked-iPhone-Purchases-Actually-Locked