# How can I check if an iphone is sim unlocked already?

Tags: iphone, sim, unlock

For the iPhone 4S and 5, is it possible to easily check if they are sim unlocked ? If so how ?

I've already seen [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/how-can-i-check-via-software-if-my-iphone-is-unlocked) but sounds a bit more complicated than I hoped. What's the simplest solution ?

Comment: That was the simplest solution.

Comment: There's two ways: Physically check by inserting a sim card, or contact AppleCare and ask them.